# Upgraded to Monotouch 4.1 Beta and get exceptions when reading SQL Lite DB

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I have just upgraded to Monotouch 4.1 and all of a sudden I'm getting errors like the one at the bottom of the question when accessing my SQLite3 DB. Can anybody point me in the right direction what could be wrong here?

The code that is causing it looks like this:

```
using(SqliteConnection oConn = this.CreateDBMSConnection())
            {
                using ( SqliteCommand oCmd = new SqliteCommand ( "SELECT Local.*, LocalObjects.intID AS intIsPopulated FROM Locals" + " LEFT JOIN LocalData ON LocalData.intID=Local.intRootObjectID", oConn ) )
                {
                    oConn.Open (  );
                    using ( var oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader (  ) )
                    {
                        while ( oReader.Read (  ) )
                        {
                            Local oLocal = this.GetLocalFromReader ( oReader );
                            aLocal.Add ( oLocal );
                        }
                    }
                    oConn.Close();
                }
            }
```

> [0xb09d6000:] EXCEPTION handling: Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException:
>   The database file is locked unable to close due to unfinalised
>   statements
>
> "" tid=0x0xb09d6000 this=0x0xa1ced20 thread handle
>   0x11f state : not waiting owns ()   at
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLiteBase.CloseConnection
>   (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionHandle) [0x00029] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteBase.cs:212
>   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionHandle.ReleaseHandle () [0x00000]
>   in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs:792
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CriticalHandle.Dispose (bool)
>   [0x00017] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.InteropServices/CriticalHandle.cs:51
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CriticalHandle.Dispose () [0x00000]
>   in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.InteropServices/CriticalHandle.cs:41
>   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Close () [0x0003d] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLite3.cs:62
>   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Close () [0x0008e] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteConnection.cs:474

Comment: Is this the first query that you are doing on your application? 

Probably you already found the problem but I thought to ask all the same.

Comment: I no longer get this exceptions with MT 5.0.2.

Comment: So maybe the best would be to close this question. What do you think?